# How to get relative file path in console application c#

Tags: c#, path, console-application

How to get relative file path in console application using c# I tried the below code but I get cannot found HttpContext , Kindly suggest in this.

```
string contents =  File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/MailTemplate/template_mail.html"));
```

Comment: Relative to which path? Have you tried `File.ReadAllText("/MailTemplate/template_mail.html");`?

Comment: Though it would be root. Relative starts with `./`. Note that the active directory by default is the one where executable is, not your `csproj` file.

Answer (score 0):

*HttpContext* is something you normally have in a web-app.
I would say, just skip that part and do it like:

```
string contents =  File.ReadAllText(@"MailTemplate\template_mail.html");
```

That is if you have the "MailTemplate" folder in the same folder as your assembly file (your program).
Good luck!

Comment: There is no guarantee that the current directory will be the directory where the assembly file is located. To be sure, you might do `Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "MailTemplate", "template_mail.html)`